# What is correct punishment for children?

Tags: parents, anger

If you see advising doesn't work with a child, are there acceptable punishments mentioned in Buddhism?

I know that Buddhism does not accept physical punishment, so I am asking about any other form of punishment.

Answer (score 1):

I like Milton Erickson's practice of physically restricting the movement of his son when he engages in the prohibited behaviour until the child undergoes a change of heart. He describes this somewhere.

Comment: is it "grounding" that you are talking about?